# Custom_field as part of a webhook URL in Jira Server

Tags: jenkins, jira, webhooks

I have several Jenkins pipelines that I want to trigger via webhook. To control which pipeline is triggered, I provide a token with the webhook URL.

I integrated the whole thing into our Jira (Atlassian Server v8.14.1) yesterday and made sure that the webhook is triggered when a ticket transitions from one state to the next. This worked as far as it could - but only with a fixed token in the URL.
In my tickets, there is a custom_field with the name staging-apps. I would now like to have this value interpreted as a token or as part of the webhook URL.
Jira offers at least a few ready-made options for variable URL components. Under the field where the URL is entered when setting up a webhook, it says:

```
You can use the following additional variables in the URL:
${board.id} ${comment.id} ${issue.id} ${issue.key} ${mergedVersion.id} ${modifiedUser.key} ${modifiedUser.name} ${project.id} ${project.key} ${sprint.id} ${version.id}
```

I tried this on a trial basis with the issue key and changed my token to it. Everything worked. However, I could not get the value of my custom_field to be used. Does this not work in principle or have I made a mistake?

What I have tried so far (of course I have always adapted the token required to trigger the pipeline to the attempt):
Worked:

```
https://jenkins.felgenoutlet.de/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=${issue.key}
```

Did not work:

```
https://jenkins.test.de/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=${issue.fields.project.key}
```

```
https://jenkins.test.de/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=${customfield_10302}
```

```
https://jenkins.test.de/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=${issue.fields.project.key}
```

Here is the relevant part of the ticket information that I retrieved via cURL. The value in customfield_10302 is the one I want to append to the URL.

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "1",
  "self": "https://jira.test.de/rest/api/2/issue/1",
  "key": "TEST-KEY",
  "fields": {
    "issuetype": {
      "self": "https://jira.test.de/rest/api/2/issuetype/2",
      "id": "2",
      "description": "Test",
      "name": "Test",
      "subtask": false
    },
    "customfield_10302": [
      "TOKEN_TO_BE_PART_OF_THE_URL"
    ]
  }
}
```